# How can .NET Core installer projects depend on the publish output?

Tags: .net-core, nsis, dotnet-cli

We have a solution containing several NSIS installers. For .NET framework we used `Costura.Fody` to combine the various DLLs into one executable, which it does as part of the build putting the result in the projects `bin` directory.

The project with the NSIS installers then simply has a dependency on those .NET projects, so that they will be built first.

```
MySolution
  CoolApp
    CoolApp.csproj
    Program.cs
  CoolAppInstaller
    CoolAppInstaller.vcxproj // project dependency on CoolApp.csproj
    CoolAppInstaller.nsi // makensis.exe custom build step consuming CoolApp/bin/$(Configuration)/
```

With .NET Core, Microsoft has this functionality built in, however it seems to only exist as part of a separate `publish` command, and thus the final output is not available at build time to the installer projects.

Can a project specify that the dependency is the "publish" rather than "build" output?

Is Microsoft intending with .NET Core/5 that creation of installers should be entirely separate from the project build (so do `dotnet build`, `dotnet publish ...`, `makensis ...` outside Visual Studio / msbuild)?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look on Visual & Installer (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller) which is a 3rd party extension specifically made for NSIS setups. It supports MSBuild variables, pre/post build events and many more so maybe with it you could tweak your build process... P.S. I was a developer of this extension.